# Join on recursive CTE in snowflake disobeys where clause

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

Consider the following views and CTE:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SubSet (Id)
AS (
          SELECT '123'
UNION ALL SELECT '456'
UNION ALL SELECT 'x'
)

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MainSet (Id)
AS (
          SELECT 123
UNION ALL SELECT 456
UNION ALL SELECT 789
)


WITH myCte (id, cnt) AS
(
  SELECT id, 1 AS cnt FROM SubSet
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id
  ,cnt + 1 FROM myCte WHERE cnt < 4 AND id <> 'x'
)
SELECT *
FROM MainSet ms
JOIN (
  SELECT id FROM myCte WHERE id <> 'x'
) X ON ms.id = X.id
```

Notice that 'x' is filtered out, both on the recursive part of the CTE and on the Sub Query from the CTE.

This worked yesterday. But as of today, it fails with "Numeric value 'x' is not recognized".

If I remove the recursive part, it won't fail:

```sql
WITH myCte (id, cnt) AS
(
  SELECT id, 1 AS cnt FROM SubSet
  --UNION ALL
  --SELECT id
  --,cnt + 1 FROM myCte WHERE cnt < 4 AND id <> 'x'
)
SELECT *
FROM MainSet ms
JOIN (
  SELECT id FROM myCte WHERE id <> 'x'
) mc ON ms.id = mc.id
```

How can the query match on 'x' when it is filtered out? It only seems to apply when using recursive CTEs.

Comment: Not sure why you would get a failure one day but not another, but I can say that the Recursive Seed (the top most query in your myCte definition) should include the filter otherwise `x` is going to show up in your results. To your point, it shouldn't show up in the filter of your subquery, but it will definitely be in the output of `myCte`.

Comment: You're correct. But my initial CTE was more complex and I didn't have the 'x'-value in the Recursive Seed.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I believe the issue stems from the `ON` clause in the final SELECT query. Snowflake is attempting an implicit cast to a number on `X.id` to make the join happen and it's failing.

I would imagine there is a query optimization step taking place that is taking the ON predicate and pushing it sooner in the execution path than the predicate in the WHERE clause. To me that feels like a bug in Snowflake, but a bug that is being exacerbated by slightly sloppy SQL and not terribly clean data where implicit casting is allowed to happen.

You can get around it by changing your ON criteria to:

```
ON cast(ms.id as string) = X.id
```

This ensures that Snowflake doesn't have to decide to either cast your `ms.id` as string or cast your `X.id` as numeric where it may make the wrong choice.

Working example (note removing the cast in this example will cause the error to pop once again):

```
WITH SubSet (Id)
AS (
    SELECT '123'
    UNION ALL SELECT '456'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'x'
)
,MainSet (Id)
AS (
    SELECT 123
    UNION ALL SELECT 456
    UNION ALL SELECT 789
)
,myCte (id, cnt) AS
(
  SELECT id, 1 AS cnt FROM SubSet
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id
      ,cnt + 1 
  FROM myCte 
  WHERE cnt < 4 AND id <> 'x'
)   
SELECT *
FROM MainSet ms
  JOIN (
    SELECT id FROM myCte WHERE id <> 'x'
  ) X ON cast(ms.id as string) = X.id;
```

Comment: That's probably it. Your solution works although in my original solution I replaced my CTE with latteral flatten. (However I doubt that my original SQL was sloppy :) I did have a CAST but who knew the filter all of the sudden would be omitted? try_to_number would have worked better though.)

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that your writing sloppy sql, it's just that SQL is meant to be very explicit and so joining a string type to a numeric type and hoping that the database makes the right decision, knowing full well it's going to HAVE to cast one or the other to pull off the join, leaves room for that database to make a bad decision. Ultimately the real slop here is Snowflake's. 1) Deciding to cast the first term over the second, or the string to number over the number to string feels silly and wrong. 2) The predicate pushdown that put the ON predicate BEFORE the sub's where predicate.